# How to run Gunicorn while still using WebSocket

Tags: python, django, docker, websocket, gunicorn

So I am using a docker for this python chat app project.

I originally had `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` as my command in docker-compose.

I found that I should switch to gunicorn if I want to deploy my app on web (like heroku). The tutorial I found say simply change the command in docker-compose to `gunicorn myproject.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000`. I did that, and all the websocket connections broke. There's a fail to send due to websocket is still in CONNECTING state, then after a while handshake fails with a status code of 404. All the setup were the same as before, except that one line. Just wondering what else I need to change to make websocket work with gunicorn? Thanks

EDIT: after some digging on the internet it seems that gunicorn wasn't supposed to be run with websocket (wsgi asgi difference I suppose?) If anyone could tell me something I could use instead of gunicorn for web server it would be extremely appreciated, or if there's any way I can run gunicorn with my django channels still working? Thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using ASGI, for asynchronous servers (websockets), you should use an asynchronous server, like Daphne or Uvicorn, the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/asgi/) has examples on how to deploy for both of them.

If you want to use uvicorn directly you could do something like:

```
uvicorn myproject.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

You can also run uvicorn *through* gunicorn using the worker class:

```
gunicorn myproject.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```